# Identity Server 4 and Asp.Net Core Identity as separate services

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have used quick start tutorial 5 [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/5_EntityFramework) to use IS4 with Asp.Net Core Identity. It works perfectly. But, as per business need, I need to extend the core identity to a large extent and add more APIs on top (will have its own DB). I thought it is a better idea to keep the user management using Asp.Net core identity and IS4 as two separate microservices, so that they can be independently scaled up and down. How can I achieve this? Any samples/references would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same requirement and am struggling to find any clue. Have you eventually done it?

Answer (score 0):

I would aim for just using Identity Server and not both ASP.NET Identity. In my understanding ASP.NET Identity is only meant to be used by one application.